# xarray : how to stack several pcolormesh figures above a map?

Tags: matplotlib, python-xarray, cartopy

For a ML project I'm currently on, I need to verify if the trained data are good or not.

Let's say that I'm "splitting" the sky into  several altitude grids (let's take 3 values for the moment) and for a given region (let's say, Europe).
One grid could be a signal reception strength (RSSI), another one the signal quality (RSRQ)
Each cell of the grid is therefor a rectangle and it has a mean value of each measurement (i.e. RSSI or RSRQ) performed in that area.
I have hundreds of millions of data

In the code below, I know how to draw a coloured mesh with xarray for each altitude: I just use xr.plot.pcolormesh(lat,lon, the_data_set); that's fine

But this will only give me a "flat" figure like this:
[RSSI value at 3 different altitudes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sucKA.png)

I need to draw all the pcolormesh() of a dataset for each altitude in such way that:

- 1: I can have the map at the bottom
- 2: Each pcolormesh() is stacked and "displayed" at its altitude
- 3: I need to add a 3d scatter plot for testing my trained data
- 4: Need to be interactive as I have to zoom in areas

For 2 and 3 above, I managed to do something using plt and cartopy :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuIu3.png)
But plt/cartopy combination is not as interactive as plotly.

But plotly doesn't have the pcolormesh functionality

And still ... I don't know in anycase, how to "stack" the pcolormesh results that I did get above.

I've been digging Internet for few days but I didn't find something that could satisfy all my criteria.

What I did to get my pcolormesh:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class super_data():
   def __init__(self, lon_bound,lat_bound,alt_bound,x_points,y_points,z_points):
      self.lon_bound = lon_bound
      self.lat_bound = lat_bound
      self.alt_bound = alt_bound
      self.x_points = x_points
      self.y_points = y_points
      self.z_points = z_points
      self.lon, self.lat, self.alt = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(self.lon_bound[0], self.lon_bound[1], self.x_points),
                                       np.linspace(self.lat_bound[0], self.lat_bound[1], self.y_points),
                                       np.linspace(self.alt_bound[0], self.alt_bound[1], self.z_points))

      self.this_xr = xr.Dataset(
                             coords={'lat': (('latitude', 'longitude','altitude'), self.lat),
                                   'lon': (('latitude', 'longitude','altitude'), self.lon),
                                   'alt': (('latitude', 'longitude','altitude'), self.alt)})

   def add_data_array(self,ds_name,ds_min,ds_max):
      def create_temp_data(ds_min,ds_max):

         data = np.random.randint(ds_min,ds_max,size=self.y_points * self.x_points)

         return data

      temp_data = []

      # Create "z_points" number of layers in the z axis
      for i in range(self.z_points):
         temp_data.append(create_temp_data(ds_min,ds_max))

      data = np.concatenate(temp_data)
      data = data.reshape(self.z_points,self.x_points, self.y_points)

      self.this_xr[ds_name] = (("altitude","longitude","latitude"),data)

   def plot(self,dataset, extent=None, plot_center=False):

      # I want t
      if np.sqrt(self.z_points) == np.floor(np.sqrt(self.z_points)):
         side_size = int(np.sqrt(self.z_points))
      else:
         side_size = int(np.floor(np.sqrt(self.z_points) + 1))

      fig = plt.figure()
      i_ax=1
      for i in range(side_size):
         for j in range(side_size):
            if i_ax < self.z_points+1:
               this_dataset = self.this_xr[dataset].sel(altitude=i_ax-1)
               # Initialize figure with subplots
               ax = fig.add_subplot(side_size, side_size, i_ax, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
               i_ax += 1
               ax.coastlines()
               this_dataset.plot.pcolormesh('lon', 'lat', ax=ax, infer_intervals=True, alpha=0.5)
            else:
               break
      plt.tight_layout()
      plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":

   # Wanted coverage :
   lons = [-15, 30]
   lats = [35, 65]
   alts = [1000, 5000]

   xarr = super_data(lons,lats,alts,10,8,3)

   # Add some fake data
   xarr.add_data_array("RSSI",-120,-60)
   xarr.add_data_array("pressure",700,1013)

   xarr.plot("RSSI",0)
```

Thanks for you help